# Bootstrap's Modal - Vertical scrollbar disapears for the first modal when i open and close a second one

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, bootstrap-modal

I have 2 bootstrap modals. When i open the first one, the vertical scroll bar works fine. Then, i have  an option from inside of the first modal which removes its opacity opacity and opens the second one. By closing the second modal i get back my first modal but instead to be able to scroll to the modal i can only scroll to the background body.

**Notice :** that happens only if i open the second modal.

I use `JQuery` in order to manipulate the modals.

Some Code:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#myModal2').modal({
        show: 'true'
    }); 

});

$('#myModal2').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   $('#myModal').css('opacity', 0);
});

$('#myModal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
   $('#myModal').css('opacity', 1);
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE:**

I temporary solve my problem by adding to the bootstrap source:

```
.modal { overflow: auto !important; }
```

It works, but now i can scroll both the body and the modal.

I'm open for other suggestions.

Comment: [Bootstrap itself doesn't support this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#overlapping-modals-not-supported). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I found the solution. When you open a modal, **bootstrap adds "modal-open" class to body**. If you close that modal, **bootstrap removes it**. When you have 2 modals, **the second one removes the "modal-open" class** of the body thats needs the first modal.

To correct that, you have to check if the first modal is open before open the second. I do it checking the modal-open class.

```
var firstModalOpen = $("body").hasClass("modal-open");
$("#second-modal").modal("show");
```

And when the second modal closes, you check if the first was opened and add class modal-open to the body.

```
$("#second-modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function()
{
    if (firstModalOpen)
        $("body").addClass("modal-open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the scroll modal and body at the same time.
this will disable the scroll of body when #modal2 is opened.

```
$('#modal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("html").css("overflow", "scroll");
});
$('#modal2').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```